# Why does the Web API method disregard the actual value and assume the first record == #1?

Tags: rest, controller, asp.net-web-api, repository, uri

This code in the WebAPI project's Repository class:

```
public DepartmentRepository()
{
    Add(new Department { Id = 0, AccountId = "7.0", DeptName = "Dept7" });
    Add(new Department { Id = 1, AccountId = "8.0", DeptName = "Dept8" });
    Add(new Department { Id = 2, AccountId = "9.0", DeptName = "Dept9" });
}
```

...called by this code in the Controller class:

```
public Department GetDepartment(int id)
{
    Department dept = repository.Get(id);
    if (dept == null)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
    return dept;
}
```

...with this in the browser:

```
http://localhost:48614/api/departments/1/
```

...returns this:

```
<Department xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DuckbillServerWebAPI.Models">
<AccountId>7.0</AccountId>
<DeptName>Dept7</DeptName>
<Id>1</Id>
</Department>
```

...which corresponds to the instance of Department with Id == 0, not Id == 1.

Passing a "0" in the REST URI fails. Passing "2" returns AccountId = "8.0", passing "3" returns AccountId = "9.0"

If "1" is converted to "First" what's the point of even giving the Ids values? I could assign them 42, 76, etc.

### UPDATE

In answer to Adrian Banks:

*"Have you checked what the value of id is in the GetDepartment call?"*

It is what is entered. For `"http://localhost:48614/api/departments/1/"` it is 1, for `"http://localhost:48614/api/departments/2/"` it is 2, for `"http://localhost:48614/api/departments/0/"` it is 0, then throws a NotFound exception.

"Also, what does the code in the Get() method of the repository look like?,"

The Repository Get is:

```
public Department Get(int id)
{
    return departments.Find(p => p.Id == id);
}
```

### UPDATE 2

In answer to Mike Wasson, here is the Add method:

```
public Department Add(Department item)
{
    if (item == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
    }
    item.Id = _nextId++;
    departments.Add(item);
    return item;
}
```

My code to add/post an item (again, based on the code Mike Wasson's article) is:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostDepartment(Department dept)
{
    dept = repository.Add(dept);
    var response = Request.CreateResponse<Department>(HttpStatusCode.Created, dept);

    string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = dept.Id });
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what the value of `id` is in the `GetDepartment` call? Also, what does the code in the `Get()` method of the repository look like?

Comment: What does the Add() method look like? In your example response, the ID is 1, so it looks like maybe the Add method is overwriting the ID. (Also where did you get this repository class?)

Comment: I haven't added an Add() method yet (will do so directly); If I understand your second question, I modeled (no pun intended) this Repository from the one in this article: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations (yours, in fact)!

Comment: @MikeWasson: Never mind about the first part of the previous comment; I've updated (Update 2) my post with that.

Comment: Ah - that was my suspicion :-) The Add method assigns the ID, overwriting any value that you posted. In fact the repository class in that article is not very good, it was only meant to illustrate Web API. (And I should probably change it...) But in a typical application, the ID might be a primary DB key and the client would not specify the ID in the POST. But that depends on the application.

Comment: @MikeWasson: Okay, make that last comment an answer, and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: From the comment thread, the repository class was adapted from this article: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations

The Add method assigns the ID, overwriting any value that you posted. The repository class in that article is really only meant to illustrate Web API. But in a typical application, the ID might be a primary DB key and the client would not specify the ID in the POST. But that depends on the application.